# Sustitución con expresión regular java

Tags: java, hashmap

Hola tengo la siguiente duda quiero remplazar los datos de mi String datos por los valores de mi hashmap

Ejemplo

```
hmap.put("NAME","JUAN");

String datos="DATOS::NAME=@NAME@;

actualmente utilizo lo siguiente para encontrar las @ y remplazar los datos 
 String buscaCaracter ="@";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(buscaCaracter);
        Matcher match =pattern.matcher(cmd);

        if(match.find()) {
            System.out.println("******ENCONTRE******\r\n");


            Iterator iterador =hmap.entrySet().iterator();
            Map.Entry datosmap;

            while(iterador.hasNext()) {
                datosmap =(Map.Entry) iterador.next();

    System.out.println(datos.replace(buscaCaracter,datosmap.getValue().toString()));
```

y salida queda asi:

```
"DATOS::NAME=JUANNAMEJUAN"
```

No se si me di a entender, de igual manera gracias!

Comment: Debe usar expresion regular? O puede usar otros metodos?

Comment: no es necesario utilizar expresiones regulares, pero fue lo primero que se me ocurrio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo parece incompleto, asi no puedo reproducir su salida.

Sin embargo, si quiere la salida sea `DATOS::NAME=JUAN` y no tiene que usar expresion regular, hay manera mas sencilla para conseguirlo.

Este solucion **no utiliza** expresion regular ni Iterator.

```java
HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hmap.put("NAME","JUAN");

String datos="DATOS::NAME=@NAME@";

// Obtener el substring "@NAME@" de 'datos'
String valorActual = datos.substring(datos.indexOf('=')+1);

// Quitar los "@" de valorActual, y luego usar este string para obtener el valor nuevo desde hmap
String valorNuevo = hmap.get(valorActual.replace("@",""));

if( valorNuevo != null){
    // Realizar el replace
    String resultado = datos.replace(valorActual,valorNuevo);

    System.out.println(resultado);
}
```